# Trying to get property of non-object when using get_post_permalink()

Tags: permalinks

I'm trying to get the permalink of a custom post type using get_post_permalink().  I need to use get_post_permalink() because I use the post_type_link filter to change the permalink for specific post types to something other than the usual.  Here is the code that I'm trying to run:

```
class Get_Department_Class {

/**
 * The department's post ID.
 *
 * @since    1.0
 * @access   public
 * @var      int    $ID    Holds the department's post ID
 */
public $ID;

/**
 * Will hold the department's post data.
 *
 * @since    1.0
 * @access   public
 * @var      array    $post    Holds the department's post data
 */
public $post;

/**
 * Will hold the department's permalink.
 *
 * @since    1.0
 * @access   protected
 * @var      string    $permalink    Holds the department's permalink
 */
protected $permalink;

/**
 * Build/construct the department.
 *
 * @since   1.0
 * @param   $post_id - allows you to pass the department's post ID or post title
 */
public function __construct( $post_id ) {
    global $wpdb, $blog_id;

    // If not main site, change $wpdb blog ID for queries
    // Will change back when we're done
    $old_blog_id = ( 1 != $blog_id ) ? $wpdb->set_blog_id( 1 ) : NULL;


    // Check against an ID
    if ( is_numeric( $post_id ) ) {

        $this->post = get_post( $post_id );

    }

    // Check against a post title
    if ( ! $this->post ) {

        $this->post = get_page_by_title( $post_id, OBJECT, 'departments' );

    }

    // Reset the blog ID
    if ( isset( $old_blog_id ) )
        $wpdb->set_blog_id( $old_blog_id );


    // No point if there's no post ID
    if ( ! ( $this->ID = isset( $this->post ) && isset( $this->post->ID ) ? $this->post->ID : NULL ) ) {
        $this->post = NULL;
        return;
    }

}

/**
 * Get the department's permalink.
 *
 * @since   1.0
 */
public function get_permalink() {

    // Make sure we have the post ID
    if ( ! $this->ID )
        return false;

    // See if the permalink is already set
    if ( isset( $this->permalink ) && ! empty( $this->permalink ) )
        return $this->permalink;

    // Get the permalink
    if ( $permalink = get_post_permalink( $this->ID ) ) {

        // Store the permalink
        $this->permalink = $permalink;
        return $this->permalink;

    }

    return false;

}
}
```

The error that is returned is "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-includes/link-template.php on line 266."  After doing some testing in the wordpress core, line 264 in the link-template.php file is returning NULL.

line 264:

```
        $post_type = get_post_type_object($post->post_type);
```

Then on line 266 the core code attempts to access a property of the $post_type object which is NULL and therefore throws the error.

I don't want to modify the core code.  Any ideas on how I can fix this?

FYI:  I'm running WP 4.5.9...

Comment: Looks like $this is not an object, maybe you want to use $post?

Comment: Sorry, I only posted a small portion of the code.  I should have put more.  So the block of code with $this->permalink is actually within a class.  The file that's throwing the error is link-template.php which is erroring because $post_type (on line 264) is not an object.

Comment: If you simply return `$permalink` instead of `return $this->permalink;` do you still get the error?  Comment out the `$this->permalink = $permalink;` just incase.

Comment: Can you post more of the code?

Comment: Perhaps you haven't called `global $post` to be able to access it?

Comment: downvoted and close voted as it is impossible to guess what part of your code is broken without access to all of it, but you start with making sure you are passing an actual existing post id.

Comment: Can you var_dump($this) and paste the value returned.

Comment: var_dump($this) is too long to post in a comment.  I did however update the code in the question to give more context.

Comment: Here is a condensed version of $this:

    object(Research_Center)[1236]
        public 'ID' => int 145
        public 'post' =>
            object(WP_Post)[1238]
            public 'ID' => int 145
            public 'post_name' => string 'cvt' (length=4)
            public 'post_type' => string 'research_centers' (length=16)
        public 'filter' => string 'raw' (length=3))
        protected 'permalink' => string 'http://www.localhost.dev/' (length=30)

Comment: To be clear, the error is being thrown by a wordpress core file.  It's because in the core the line `$post_type = get_post_type_object($post->post_type);` is returning null but later in the function it attempts to access a property of the $post_type object. Not sure how to work around this without modding the core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that it's an issue is because I'm using switch_to_blog() on a multisite.  The post_type doesn't exist on the current blog.  It exists only on the main blog.  Since the post_type doesn't exist, the get_post_type_object() function is returning null.

What I did to fix this is create a custom_get_post_permalink function that also takes a blog_id argument and therefore changes to the appropriate blog_id on the multisite to create the post_type_object correctly.

Comment: You can mark your answer as the correct answer.